# How to see any changes (new row) in mongoDB?

Tags: c#, winforms, mongodb, collections, onchange

Is there any way to observe each `collection` (or even one) in `mongoDB`? Now I think about timer to check document number or last Id, but maybe there is some possibility to implement mechanism like `newDocumentAddedEvent`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no triggers in MongoDB (yet?), but if you're running a [replica set](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets) (as you should), your app can pretend to be a catching-up secondary, [tail](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors) the [oplog collection](http://ru.wiki.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets+-+Oplog) and get information about new inserts/updates.

This is a very efficient approach (mongodb itself uses it for the replication).

Comment: Do you have maybe some example in C#?

Comment: But first thing I store data on one node (I haven't other option) so I think there's no need to use replication. And if not, I need other way to see changes.

Comment: You can create a replica set with just one node. That'll give you the oplog collection. Now you can tail it.